# Google stackdriver default port blocked by firewall rule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

because of a firewall rule I am not able to get data to google stack-driver logging.

I dont know on which port stack-driver collects data. I need this to remove/modify that particular firewall rule which is blocking the data to go to stack-driver.

I came to this conclusion because for one region I am getting the stack-driver logs and for one region I am not. For both regions(Central and East) I have a deny rule with priority "999" which denies all the egress traffic.

But for one region(central) i am getting logs in stack-driver, which means there is a rule with higher priority (<999) which is allowing that data but that rule is not present in East region.

I am not sure on which port stack-driver collect logs to pin point which firewall rule is allowing that data for Central region. I have 400+ rules for both the regions so comparing them is not possible.

I just want to know the port number and i can search for that particular "Allow" fire-wall rule and can apply on East region too.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that Google Stackdriver requires any TCP ports to be open in your firewall to function. Instead Stackdriver uses `authorization scopes`.

SSH into your instance. Run the following command:

```
`curl --silent --connect-timeout 1 -f -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes`
```

Look for these two scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.admin
```

If they are missing, go to the Google Cloud Console and add these scopes to your VM. Reboot your instance.

Comment: I have "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" added to all our VMs. but this is there for all VMs. for me only East region is not working. It has to be a firewall isuue.

Comment: I have Stackdriver logging and monitoring working with NO open ports. Did you at least take my advice and verify that you have the scopes from inside the VM?

Comment: As I mentioned this is the only scope in my VMs -- "googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"  ..

Comment: @Badmaash do you know what ports are used by stackdriver monitoring agent?